# Form Submission Leads to Broken URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm using [this javascript form](https://codecanyon.net/item/smart-forms/7254656) on my WordPress site but when I submit it won't go to the actual .php file that processes forms.

This is at the top of my form:

```
<form method="post" action="www.example.com/wp-content/themes/foundry/php/smartprocess.php" id="contact">
```

But when I click submit, it takes me to a broken URL that adds that URL to the base URL of the submission page like this:

http://example.com/form/www.example.com/wp-content/themes/foundry/php/smartprocess.php

I have the .php file stored at that exact location, but it won't go directly to it. I've triple checked the file location and it matches up and everything.

Comment: put `action="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/foundry/php/smartprocess.php"` full url including `http://` if you are puting URL static otherwise use always system base_url (app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepend your `www` with `//`. This is an agnostic method of resolving URL's based on the existing schema. For instance, if accessed over `http` it would resolve as `http://www` otherwise, if it were secured, it would resolve as `https://www`.

Furthermore, you should not be posting to a `Raw PHP` file in Wordpress. You should post to the relevant URL and then in your `functions.php` or other `plugin file` hook into the action to handle the saving of the post:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_smart_process_post');
function save_smart_proces_post($post_id) {
    if(isset($_POST['my_form_values'])) {
        //this is a form that can be processed by your custom form functions.
    }
}
```

Note that for a minified example, I've omitted code concerning `CSRF` tokens, but you should absolutely consider utilizing them.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it, felt dumb after realizing that's what it was.